# String compare function works when defined in contract but not in library

Tags: solidity, string

I have a very basic string helper library that defines a function to compare two strings like so:

```
library StringLib {
  function compareTwoStrings(string memory s1, string memory s2)
    public
    pure
    returns (bool)
  {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(s1)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(s2));
  }
}
```

I import it in my contract with `import './StringLib.sol';` and use it with `StringLib.compareTwoStrings(s1, s2)`.

For some reason, this results in a bytecode error: `Error: invalid bytecode (argument="bytecode",`. I've tried using hardcoded strings (`StringLib.compareTwoStrings('A', 'B')`) and hit the same issue.

However, if I define the exact same function directly in my contract code, it works without a problem.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong at the implementation contract, but I've been able to successfully use your lib.

Code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

library StringLib {
  function compareTwoStrings(string memory s1, string memory s2)
    public
    pure
    returns (bool)
  {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(s1)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(s2));
  }
}

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

contract Contract{
    function compare(string memory a, string memory b) public pure returns (bool){
        return StringLib.compareTwoStrings(a, b);
    }
}
```

Note: you could use an import statement to import the library, it doesn't make any difference. Resulting code would effectively be same as above.